# Django - importError at /blog. (No module named urls)

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, python-2.7

While studying Django tutorial (the book is Python Web Development with Django), I've been getting an import error.

I've looked for a solution on here and with Google, but I couldn't find one that worked.

My error is `ImportError at /blog. No module named urls.`

I'm using **django 1.5.1**.

My files are structure -

```
 - mysite
     manage.py
     - blog
        __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        - templates
            archive.html
     - mysite
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

**mysite/blog/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from mysite.blog.views import archive

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', archive),
)
```

**mysite/blog/view.py**

```
from django.template import loader, Context
from django.http import HttpResponse
from mysite.blog.models import BlogPost

def archive(requset):
    posts = BlogPost.objects.all()
    t = loader.get_template("archive.html")
    c = context({ 'posts': posts })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

**mysite/mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
       url(r'^blog/', include('mysite.blog.urls')),
      # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

)
```

**setting.py**

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'blog',
)
```

**traceback**

```
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response

                            resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in resolve

                    for pattern in self.url_patterns:

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in url_patterns

                patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in urlconf_module

                    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module

            __import__(name)

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/han/Django/mysite/mysite/urls.py in <module>

               url(r'^blog/', include('mysite.blog.urls')),

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py in include

                urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module

            __import__(name)

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
```

Comment: can you edit the question with the entire stack trace ?

Comment: Did you include `mysite` in your `settings.py` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change this line:

```
url(r'^blog/', include('mysite.blog.urls')),
```

to this:

```
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried some solution. one of the solution I tried. but It coulndn't give me... anyway, thank you!

Comment: The very same error? You'll have to copy the full stacktrace in the question

Answer (score 0):

My solution is here:

mysite/blog/urls.py

```
from mysite.blog.views import archive
```

to

```
from blog.views import archive
```

mysite/blog/view.py

```
from mysite.blog.models import BlogPost
```

to

```
from blog.models import BlogPost
```

mysite/mysite/urls.py

```
url(r'^blog/', include('mysite.blog.urls')),
```

to

```
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
```

Here I suggest you to set DEBUG true in settings.py . when there is mistake, it can tell you the place where the application stop. In this case, you just need to jump to this place. It would be better to debug.

Answer (score 0):

change this file mysite/blog/urls.py
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
to
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem but I did just the opposite of what @Haimei did

mysite/blog/urls.py
    from blog.views import archive changed it to

```
from mysite.blog.views import archive
```

and it worked.

also make sure that .defaults is removed from
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url